# Multibooting different distros

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bootloader

As in this post (https://www.linux.com/answers/how-can-i-dual-boot-two-or-more-linux-distros) I would like to multiboot linux ! I am on a Dell Vostro 3550 laptop with 1tb HDD, I am not a complete noob at installing linux and the main question I had was that someone in the post linked above said that the last distro that we install is going to be the main/default one.

1. Does that mean that the boot loader of the last one should be installed on the hard drive (in installer: Something Else -> Device for Boot Loader Installation (/dev/sdx)) ?
2. Is it okay if I have already installed Ubu's boot loader on my HDD (/dev/sda, in my case) and then, I can install the other systems boot loaders on their own partitions ? e.g. I make a partition for Arch and then the device for boot loader installation is /dev/sda5 (which is Arch's EXT4 partition) ?

Thank you,
Js

Comment: I have never been offered the option of installing on different partitions, as far as I have noticed. Different physical HDD yes but not partitions. Something else is you way to go.

Comment: UEFI or BIOS. With UEFI all installs can share the ESP - efi system partition. But with BIOS you only have one MBR for boot loader and that should be your main system. With Ubuntu's grub it auto installs to sda, unless you choose Something Else and choose where to install boot loader. Not sure about other installs. But Ubuntu's grub should be able to find and boot other installs.

Comment: Exactly, but will Ubu's GRUB detect and be able to boot properly if I install Arch's boot loader in, say, /dev/sda5 ? Standard Boot: I boot, then Ubu's GRUB loads, then I select Arch's boot loader in the GRUB, and it boots Arch. Is that it ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out.

Without talking about Arch (because of its numerous options), it was fairly simple.

I first installed Ubuntu and in Ubuquity (its installer) I pre-partitioned my hard drive for the other distros. I then installed each distro and finally, at the complete end, re-installed Ubuntu. I chose my hard drive as the device for the Bootloader's installation (/dev/sdx), and installed as normal.

Now, when I boot my computer, it goes this way: Ubu's bootloader --> choose the distro. If it's Ubu, then boot into Ubu. If it's something else, then boot into that 'something else'.

Hope it helps !

Note: I answered my own question for further information if people run into my post and seek help :)